# Use of private data variables in simple POJO

Tags: java, private, encapsulation

Recently I was going through the concept of Encapsulation in Java. I was wondering if making data variables private along with public setter methods really make sense in simple POJO class? Please refer below POJO:

```
public class Employee{
    
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private int age;
    
    public Employee(){        
    }

    public Employee(String id, String name, String department, int age){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.age = age;
    }
 
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
 
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
 
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
  
}
```

I mean why am I making the name variable private when I can anyway change it using the setter method?

Comment: In case you find it overkill to write simple setter/getter methods, most IDEs have a "generate getter / setter" feature to simply generate all methods for you. If you still find it cumbersome to have all these methods in your class, take a look at the "Lombok" library.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, it'll be the very basic

```
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Where it's identical to just doing `employee.name = "william hammond"`. But imagine a case where you'd like to do implement something like a `private String normalize(string username)` method where you maybe make it all lower case, check for a valid name or prevent unicode entries. If you make `name` public initially you'll have users doing `employee.name = "whatever they want :) 123"` and you'll lose the ability to enforce that constraint.

Also see [Why use getters and setters/accessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors)

Answer (score 0):

Using getters/setters is just considered good practice, but it can often be overkill - like in your example.

If you have methods that mutate the variable before setting, then it's nice to have getters/setters for the basic fields as well to maintain consistent code style.

Here's a good article on it:
https://dzone.com/articles/getter-setter-use-or-not-use-0

Answer (score 0):

Let's have an example:

```java
public class Example {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Example(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

This class has 3 **properties** (firstName, lastName, fullName), but only two **fields** (firstName, lastName). It makes sense, because a full name can be retrieved by combining first and last name.

However, I've noticed that I call `getFullName()` a lot of times in my program, but I almost never call `getFirstName()` and `getLastName()`. This slows down my program, because I need to create a new string each time `getFullName()` is called. So, I've refactored my code to have a better performance:

```java
public class Example {
    private String fullName;

    public Example(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return fullName.split(" ")[0];
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return fullName.split(" ")[1];
    }
    
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

Now my code works faster when calling `getFullName()`, but slower when calling `getFirstName()` and `getLastName()`, however It's exactly what I needed. From outside the class, nothing really've changed.

---

As you can see by the given example, **fields** describe how your class uses the computer's memory, but not necessarily which **properties** your class has. This is why **fields** should be considered an **implementation detail** and therefore be private to a class.